# Steam - location and game censorship

Tags: steam, fallout

From what I could read Steam offers differing versions of the games. For example non-censored US Fallout and non-US censored Fallout. I would like to go with the genuine versions. What do I need to do to get the right version? Do I just need to manually change "download location" in the Steam settings to one of the US locations? I can also see that there is a "Country: xxx" in account settings. Does it affect it?

Comment: From what I've read, if you live in Germany [it doesn't matter anymore](https://blogjob.com/oneangrygamer/2016/02/fallout-3-manages-to-get-unbanned-in-germany/) for F3 (or 4). Just make sure you get the New Vegas [Ultimate Edition](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fallout/comments/1gb8db/id_like_to_finally_buy_fallout_3_nv_on_steam_from/).

Answer (score 1):

Changing download location may work. But if you really want to make sure you can find someone in the country that has the version you want to gift you the game. Or you could just create a new account and choose the country you want during setup and then just gift the game to yourself.

Comment: For some games, the language setting is the key: "With things as they are now, my game is in English and is uncut, if however I change my steam language to German, then STEAM immediately starts DLing a patch afterwards which my game is cut. If I then go and change STEAM back to English it again DLs a patch, and I once again have the uncut version." –[Half-Life Steam forum](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2583493). 'gifting' is also mentioned, plus one.

Comment: For some games, the "ID" number referenced when you run the game makes the differance. When L4D 2 came out, I could only purchase the censored version. But change the ID in 2 .bat files to point to the uncensored game, and boom-headshot.